# python changing string to date

Tags: python, pandas, string-formatting, date-formatting

I have 2 date columns (begin and end) in a data frame where the dates are in the following string format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'. How can I change these into date format in python? I also want to create a new column that shows the difference in days between the end and begin dates.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have take a look at [time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime) for the first part ? And then you can subtract one to the other and you'll end up with a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of pandas you can pass a format argument to `to_datetime`:

```
In [11]: dates = ["2014-08-27 19:53:06.000", "2014-08-27 19:53:15.002"]

In [12]: pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
Out[12]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-08-27 19:53:06, 2014-08-27 19:53:15.002000]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Note: it isn't necessary in this case to pass format but it may be faster/tighter:

```
In [13]: pd.to_datetime(dates,)
Out[13]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-08-27 19:53:06, 2014-08-27 19:53:15.002000]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` module has everything you need to play around with dates. Note that in the format you describe `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` the `%f` does not appear in the [known directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) and is not included in my answer

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = ["2014-08-27 19:53:06", "2014-08-27 19:53:15"]
# That's where the conversion happens from string to datetime objects
datetimes = [datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for date in dates]
print datetimes
>> [datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 27, 19, 53, 6), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 27, 19, 53, 15)
# Here a simple subtraction will give you the result you are looking for return a timedelta object
delta = datetimes[1] - datetimes[0]
print type(delta), delta
>> <type 'datetime.timedelta'>, 0:00:09
```

Comment: See the table here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior, `%f` *is* included.

Comment: Thanks @joris I have to start using python 3 !

Comment: Your link was also python 3 :-), but the difference was that you linked to the `time` module, while here `datetime` is relevant